# How to retrieve function input javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've got the following code that produces a dynamically created image button and panel in asp.net: -

```
Panel panBlocks = new Panel();
panBlocks.ID = "PanBlockQuestionID" + recordcount.ToString();
panBlocks.Width = 1300;
panBlocks.Height = 50;
panBlocks.BackColor = Color.Pink;

ImageButton cmdBlocks = new ImageButton();
cmdBlocks.ImageUrl = "~/Images/block3.png";
cmdBlocks.ID = "lblImg" + recordcount.ToString();
cmdBlocks.Attributes["class"] = "liQuestionsLabel2";
cmdBlocks.Width = 30;
cmdBlocks.Attributes.Add("OnMouseOver", "showPanel(" + "CPH_Body_" + panBlocks.ClientID.ToString() + ")");
cmdBlocks.Attributes.Add("OnMouseOut", "hidePanel();");

li.Controls.Add(cmdBlocks);                
li.Controls.Add(panBlocks);
```

When I hover over the image I want it to display a particular panel. I've added the `"CPH_Body_" + panBlocks.ClientID.ToString()` as an attribute.

I've got the following javascript code:

```
function showPanel(PanelID)
{
   document.getElementById("CPH_Body_liQuestions1").style.height = "40px";
}
```

How do I retrieve the `PanelID` in the javascript please as it looks like an array. I need to retrieve this so I know which panel to display please.

Comment: Where do you need to retrieve it? What do you mean by "it looks like an array"?

Comment: like this? `document.getElementById(PanelID[0])`

Comment: how you call `showPanel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC (!!):

Change this :

```
cmdBlocks.Attributes.Add("OnMouseOver", "showPanel(" + "CPH_Body_" + panBlocks.ClientID.ToString() + ")");
```

To:

```
cmdBlocks.Attributes.Add("OnMouseOver", "showPanel('" +  panBlocks.ClientID.ToString()   + "')");
```

And change this :

```
function showPanel(PanelID)
{
   document.getElementById("CPH_Body_liQuestions1").style.height = "40px";
}
```

To

```
function showPanel(PanelID)
{
   document.getElementById(PanelID).style.height = "40px";
}
```

Comment: methinks `panBlocks.ClientIdMode="static";` not need. Possibly enough add attributes after panel was added to container

Comment: @Grundy nope. see [here](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/703_Understanding_ClientIDMode_Mode_Feature_in_ASP_net_4_0.aspx) `static` allow me to define the ID as I want without prefix and postfix

Comment: example : http://i.imgur.com/hWOgeDN.png ( Also notice OP's `panBlocks.ID = "PanBlockQuestionID" + recordcount.ToString();`)

Comment: i mean - `ClientID` should return id with all needed prefixes

Comment: @Grundy Yes. i've checked it. it generates unique  . so there is no need for static. editing.

Comment: possiblie need adding quotes here: `"showPanel('" +  panBlocks.ClientID.ToString()   + "')"`

Comment: Hi Royi, I've tried what you've suggested but I'm getting: Javascript runtime error: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference i'm afraid.